# How to enable "Disable Cache" in browser network tab?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser-cache

Hy there,
I am building a web page in jsfiddle, and every time i run the script it load whole libraries again so i decide to put it into cache, by enabling the "disable cache" in the dev tool

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcob9.png

Is there any way to enable or disable the cache by js or html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check on `Disable cache`, exact opposite happens to what you're trying to do. The browser fetches the latest resources. instead of the using the ones which it has already cached.

[image]

So, this is how your configurtion will look like when `Disable cache` is enabled. To enable caching you might like to uncheck it.

To enable cache using JavaScript, you can utilise the browser's [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) API.

Comment: Yes that part i understand but can i do it with javascript or html ?

Comment: Yes you can. But it's not that straight forward. You'll have to create service workers and cache the resources. Also, you can refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

Comment: Thankyou for the support